# Find the general equation and a vector equation of the plane that passes through these points

Tags: linear-algebra

Here are the three points:

$$P(1,2,4), Q(1,-1,6), R(1,4,8)$$

Here is my work that I have done so far:

**General Equation:**

No, idea what this is actually....

**Vector Equation:**

$$(x,y,z) = (1,2,4) + t_1(0,-3,2) + t_2(0,2,4) $$

I followed my textbook's steps where I get two vectors by doing Q-P and R-P, however my answer doesn't match up with the book's

The book's vector equation is
$$(x,y,z) = (1,0,0) + t_1(0,1,0) + t_2(0,0,1) $$

Can someone explain to my why my answer is wrong, I can't seem to understand why it doesn't match up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that the plane is actually $x=1$ since this contains $P,\,Q,\,R$ and there's only one plane, containing $P,\,Q,\,R$ since these are not collinear.
Btw, general equation could be obtained as $[Q-P\times R-P]\cdot (X-P)=0$, where $X=(x,y,z)$.
Your vector equation is correct too, since a vector plane equation is not unique:
$$\begin{align}
(1,2,4)+t_1(0,−3,2)+t_2(0,2,4)
&=(1,0,0)+t_1(0,−3,2)+(t_2+1)(0,2,4)\\
&=(1,0,0)+\left(t_1-\frac{t_2}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)(0,−4,0)+(t_2+1)(0,2,4)\\
&=(1,0,0)+\left(t_1-\frac{t_2}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)(0,−4,0)+
\left(\frac{t_1}{2}+\frac{t_2}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)(0,0,4)\\
&=(1,0,0)+\frac{-2t_1+t_2+1}{8}(0,1,0)+
\frac{t_1+t_2+1}{8}(0,0,1)\\
\end{align}$$
It's the same plane, as $-2t_1+t_2+1$ and $t_1+t_2+1$ are linearly-independent.

Comment: Can you explain why the plane is x = 1?

Comment: $P,\,Q,\,R$ all have $x$-coordinate $1$. So these three all lays in $x=1$. As any three non-collinear points uniquely determine the plane, passing through these, there are no other plane than $x=1$, passing through $P,\,Q,\,R$.